# c# Winforms - Passing control references between classes/dll's

Tags: c#, winforms

I have written a piece of software that supports plugin architecture.  On the main GUI is a TextBox that I use to update the user with the status of the processes.

When I load a plugin, is it bad practice to pass a reference for that Textbox through to the plugin so that it can update it from within.  Is this too highly coupled?  Would it better practise with events?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you create an interface for communications between the plugin and its host. That would have an `UpdateStatus` method, and the implementation would update the textbox.

If you really only have one thing to do (updating the status) then you *could* use a simple delegate... but it seems likely that you may need more operations over time.

Comment: The plugin communicates with the main app through an interface already, so I will add the extra method.  I did thnk of this initially, but came upon a different problem:  The main class of the plugin will have this method.  How do I then activate this method from other classes within the plugin, I tried making it static, but it wouldnt allow it as I am using an interface?  Thanks

Comment: @Darren: That's up to the plug-in. Presumably the classes within the plugin are creating each other - so they should be able to provide the IPluginHost (or whatever) as a dependency just like any other.

Comment: Hi Jon,  Can I just clarify this.  When you say create an UpdateStatus Method and have the implementation update the TextBox, do you mean pass a reference to the TextBox through to the plugin which is updated within the UpdateStatus method?  Thanks.